# How does Pydantic implement overriding defaults in the Config class?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, pydantic

When you create a Pydantic BaseModel class, you can override the class Config class like so:

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    name: str = "Tom"

    class Config:
       title = "Custom Title"
```

That then overrides the default values of BaseConfig:

```
class BaseConfig:
    title: Optional[str] = None
    anystr_lower: bool = False
    anystr_strip_whitespace: bool = False
    min_anystr_length: int = 0
    max_anystr_length: Optional[int] = None
    validate_all: bool = False
    extra: Extra = Extra.ignore
    allow_mutation: bool = True
    frozen: bool = False
    allow_population_by_field_name: bool = False
    use_enum_values: bool = False
    fields: Dict[str, Union[str, Dict[str, str]]] = {}
    validate_assignment: bool = False
    error_msg_templates: Dict[str, str] = {}
    arbitrary_types_allowed: bool = False
    orm_mode: bool = False
    getter_dict: Type[GetterDict] = GetterDict
    alias_generator: Optional[Callable[[str], str]] = None
    keep_untouched: Tuple[type, ...] = ()
    schema_extra: Union[Dict[str, Any], 'SchemaExtraCallable'] = {}
    json_loads: Callable[[str], Any] = json.loads
    json_dumps: Callable[..., str] = json.dumps
    # key type should include ForwardRef, but that breaks with python3.6
    json_encoders: Dict[Union[Type[Any], str], AnyCallable] = {}
    underscore_attrs_are_private: bool = False
```

How is this subclass Config implemented so that you can override the defaults?

For example, how can I implement a similar design pattern for this class design:

```
class BaseConfig:
    n_legs = 2
    n_arms = 2


class BasePerson:
    Config = BaseConfig
    name: str


class Person(BasePerson):
    class Config:
        n_arms = 1
```

so that when you do

```
p = Person()
```

you get

```
p.Config.n_arms == 1
p.Config.n_legs == 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with class inheritance

```py
class Person(BasePerson):
    class Config(BasePerson.Config):
        n_arms = 1
```